# Need Guidance with processing a stripe payment due to Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch error

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I have been working on processing a connection to a payment gateway and have run into a fetch issue.

I have been following this guide https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/stripe-node-js

But I have run into a fetch error and I am unsure of how to proceed.

below is my check out modal component where the items in the cart are shown, a user can see the items added to the cart and remove them and this is where the payment is supposed to be processed.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import products from './product'
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"; 

import cart from '../context/cart'
import { CartContext } from '../context/cart';
const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: "100%",
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};
export default function BasicModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_35p114pH8oNuHX72SmrvsFqh00Azv3ZaIA");


  const { cartItems, addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart, getCartTotal } = useContext(CartContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    // storing input name
    localStorage.getItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  }, [cartItems])



// payment is processed here


  const makePayment = async () => { 
    const stripe = await loadStripe("pk_test_35p"); 
    const body = { cartItems }; 
    const headers = { 
      "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    }; 
  
    const response = await fetch( 
      "localhost:8000/api/create-checkout-session", 
      { 
        method: "POST", 
        headers: headers, 
        body: JSON.stringify(body), 
      } 
    ); 
  
    const session = await response.json(); 
  
    const result = stripe.redirectToCheckout({ 
      sessionId: session.id, 
    }); 
    if (result.error) { 
      console.log(result.error); 
    } 
  }; 
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}   >

        ({cartItems.length})
        Check Out</Button>
      <Modal
      disableScrollLock={true}
      fullScreen={true}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <>
            <div className="flex-col flex items-center bg-white gap-8 p-10 text-black text-sm">
              <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Cart</h1>
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
  
  
                {cartItems.map((item) => (
                  <div className="flex justify-between items-center" key={item.id}>
                    <div className="flex gap-4">
                      <img src={item.imageId} alt={item.title} className="rounded-md h-24" />
                      <div className="flex flex-col">
                        <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">{item.title}</h1>
                        <p className="text-gray-600">{item.price}</p>
                        <p className="text-gray-600">{item.description}</p>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex gap-4">
                      <button
                        className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                        onClick={() => {
                          addToCart(item)
                        }}
                      >
                        +
                      </button>
                      <p>{item.quantity}</p>
                      <button
                        className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                        onClick={() => {
                          removeFromCart(item)
                        }}
                      >
                        -
                      </button>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
              {
                cartItems.length > 0 ? (
                  <div className="flex flex-col justify-between items-center">
                    <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Total: ${getCartTotal()}</h1>
                    <button
                      className="px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 text-white text-xs font-bold uppercase rounded hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700"
                      onClick={() => {
                        clearCart()
                      }}
                    >
                      Clear cart
                    </button>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={makePayment} >Check out
                      </Button> 
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <h1 className="text-lg font-bold">Your cart is empty</h1>
                  </>
                )
              }
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">      
 </div>
          </>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

below is my node server where I am trying to process the back end

```
const cors = require("cors"); 
const express = require("express"); 
 
const stripe = require("stripe")("sMK"); 
 
const app = express(); 
 
// Middlewares here 
app.use(express.json()); 
 
// Routes here 
app.get("/", (req, res) => { 
  res.send("Hello World"); 
}); 
 
app.use(cors({origin: "*",}))
// Listen 
app.listen(8000, () => { 
  console.log("Server started at port 8000"); 
}); 

app.post("/api/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => { 
    const { product } = req.body; 
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({ 
      payment_method_types: ["card"], 
      line_items: [ 
        { 
          price_data: { 
            currency: "inr", 
            product_data: { 
              name: product.name, 
            }, 
            unit_amount: product.price * 100, 
          }, 
          quantity: product.quantity, 
        }, 
      ], 
      mode: "payment", 
      success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success", 
      cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/failure", 
    }); 
    res.json({ id: session.id }); 
  });
```

Comment: It seems like your front-end and back-end are having trouble communicating. Can you be explicit about the error?  What is the exact text of the error message?  At which line of code does it get thrown?

Comment: it looks like the error is on line 49 of the modal .js  "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
Fetch API cannot load localhost:8000/api/create-checkout-session. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch command needs to specify the URL scheme, which for `localhost` should be `http:`.

Try changing this

```js
const response = await fetch( 
      "localhost:8000/api/create-checkout-session", 
      { 
        method: "POST", 
        headers: headers, 
        body: JSON.stringify(body), 
      } 
    );
```

to this

```js
const response = await fetch( 
      "http://localhost:8000/api/create-checkout-session", 
      { 
        method: "POST", 
        headers: headers, 
        body: JSON.stringify(body), 
      } 
    );
```